# Como usar o POST em um json para um servidor Http

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api

Eu estava pensando como posso fazer um  POST de um json para um servidor http. O código que estou usando para fazer o json é o seguinte:

```
Person person= new Person();
                    product.FirtsName = "Ola";
                    product.ID = 1;
                    product.age= 10;


                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

E esta é a classe `Person`:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirtsName { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, vou alterar sua classe `Pedro`, para uma classe chamada `Pessoa` e arrumar nomenclaturas. Decida se vai usar propriedades em inglês ou em português. Neste caso, vou utilizar as propriedades em inglês:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

Ajustado isso, você precisa de um método *assíncrono* e de um objeto `HttpClient`. Neste caso optei por retornar um `bool` caso a operação retorne um código de sucesso:

```
/// <summary>
/// Cria uma pessoa
/// </summary>
/// <param name="person">Objeto 'Person'</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task<bool> CreatePersonAsync(Person person)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("endreço da sua web api");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // Transforma o objeto em json
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);

    // Envia o json para a API e verifica se obteve sucesso
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("Controller da sua API para criar a pessoa", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

> Note que em "endreço da sua web api" é o endereço http da sua API.

Por exemplo: http://criapessoa.azurewebsites.net/api/

> Note que em "Controller da sua API para criar a pessoa" é o apenas o
>   nome do Controller responsável por criar a "pessoa" (objeto Person).

Por exemplo: se dentro da sua API o Controller responsável por criar as pessoas se chame "Pessoa", é esse nome que vai colocar.

#### Utilizando o método

Para chamar esse método e esperar o resultado, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
// Método para criar a pessoa e enviar para a Web API
public async void CreatePerson()
{
   // Cria um objeto "Person"
   var person = new Person()
   {
       ID = 1,
       FirstName = "Pedro",
       Age = 10
    }

    // Cria a pessoa e armazena o resultado
    var isOK = await CreatePersonAsync(person);

    // Verifica se obteve sucesso
    if(isOK)
    {
        // Pessoa criada com sucesso
    }
}
```

> Note que o método precisa ser `async`, pois dentro dele iremos chamar o
>   método `async` que criamos anteriormente para criar a pessoa na  Web
>   API. Além disso, utilizamos a diretiva `await` para esperar o método
>   executar e retornar.

Comment: E como é que eu posso adicionar headers no seu código ?

Comment: Já tem um header adicionado na seguinte linha: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(). Pode adicionar mais da mesma forma.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @PedroAzevedo Alterei algumas coisas na resposta. Desaclopei o código que estava criando o objeto Person de dentro do método http e coloquei um exemplo de uso do método e da forma mais "correta" para fazer o que deseja.

Comment: Qual é a referencia  que se tem de usar para usar o HttpClient?

Comment: O using é esse: using System.Net.Http;

Comment: No meu condigo não consigo usar esse using

Comment: Qual tipo de projeto você está utilizando? WPF, Asp.Net, WinForms?

Comment: console .net mas não sei o porque de não aparecer

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64360/discussion-between-perozzo-and-pedro-azevedo).

Comment: ainda não tenho

Comment: Fala pelo chat.